# As though/as if

Tags: grammar

I sometimes hear native speakers saying things like, "He pretended as though as if he didn't hear anything."
Is it grammatically correct? If so, how do you use "as though as if"? Is that a common usage?
Thank you.

Comment: Neither is needed since *pretended* already carries the idea of *as though*. Try "He pretended *that* he didn't hear anything" instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to say:

He pretended as if/though he hadn't heard anything. (in reference to one utterance)

For a temporary time period (for example, he's using a chainsaw)

He pretended as if/though he couldn't hear anything.